# Advanced Filter VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

this is my first question on stackoverflow...I should also say that I am not a very good programmer.

I have a spreadsheet with approximatly 33000 rows / 7 columns and have to apply a filter with multiple criteria (# of criteria ranges from 1 to 500) to these data. I have written a program (macro) using Excels Advanced Filter to automates this. It works great and is very quick (approx 0.5 sec). However, as soon as I place a command button on the spreadsheet to run this program the program slows right down to anywhere between 7 and 180 sec (the more criteria the slower the program). I have tried / searched everywhere but have not been able to find a solution to overcome this problem! Any help is greatly welcome!!!

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code of the program (macro) that you have written.

Comment: ekad, here is the code...Start = Timer
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1:G33523").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:= _
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A83"), CopyToRange:=Range("J2"), Unique:=False
    finish = Timer - Start
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 11) = finish    As you can see, this is a very simple program. When I trigger this with a command button, the execution takes 9.5 sec vers 0.23 sec when triggered from the ribbon... btw thanks for taking the time to look at this!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need this button there?? you could trigger action from ribbon (`View >> Macros >> View Macros` or `Developer >> Macros`) or directly from IDE. Finally, you could try to trigger action by event (`SelectionChange`) when user click in certain cell. See example below.

```
'Add in your sheet in Cell E1 text like 'Click to run macro' and 
'fill it yellow or with other color to resemble a button

'Goto Sheet module and add the code below-
'-check first if you don't have a SelectionChange macro already there

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Address(False, False) = "E1" Then

            Target.Offset(1, 0).Select
            MyFilteringMacro

        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there, i need to trigger this filter via a command button...the filter criteria are selected via a list box and the filter is then triggered with a command button... The filter is part of a larger program and, because it is so slow, makes this program quite user unfriendly! Thanks for taking the time to look at this...